# google Play game Leaderboard in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-play, google-play-games

```
I have used Google play game leaderboard in my iOS app.i am submitting score from my and fetch score from there. i am using following method to submit score

`[score submitScoreWithCompletionHandler: ^(GPGScoreReport *report, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
    // Handle the error
  } else {
    // Analyze the report, if you'd like
  }
}];`

and below code to present leaderboard
```

`NSString *targetLeaderboardId = @"my id"; 
   [[GPGLauncherController sharedInstance] presentLeaderboardWithLeaderboardId:targetLeaderboardId];`

but fetching score takes to much time.is there any way to reload or refresh leaderboard data.

anyone have any idea!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google Play Games Services for iOS has been deprecated, so I would not recommend putting too much time into it.  More information: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/focusing-our-google-play-games-services.html

Comment: actually i have already integrated  Google Play Games Services before deprecation is  declared.